# Is Windows Workflow Foundation designed to do this?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation

I've recently taken on management duties for a project that involves the use of Workflow Foundation, and I know virtually nothing about it.

With regard to WF, our application processes medical payments. Before a payment can be approved it must go through a potentially complex approval process. The more expensive the payment, the more complex the process. Each of our clients will have different approval processes.

Ideally, we would like to provide our clients with a screen where they can model the approval process, and then map those processes (and associated conditions) to WF.

Is this possible, and is this the right job for Workflow Foundation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like what WF4 was designed for. You can even integrate the designer into your own application so that your users can create their own workflows.

Comment: Am I correct that in order to do what you describe (integrate the designer into our app), we would need to provide the basic workflow building blocks (Activities ?) and then the user can arrange these building blocks/ Activities anyway they choose to as long as it's legal (based on how we define what legal is)?

Comment: What about the versioning story? I.e. when you release a new version  which is not compatible with the customised workflows?